# Service asking credential

Tags: service

I have mapped SharePoint ISAPI folder and create service in it. When accessing it ask me for credentials. I want this service not to ask for credentials. How can this be done?

```
/_vti_bin/RecruitmentWCF/Recruitment.svc/addnewprospect
```

Comment: What type of authentication is your SharePoint server using (for example: NTLM, Kerberos, etc.)?

Comment: it is using NTLM.

Comment: Are you initially prompted for credentials when you access your SharePoint site from the browser or is the only time you are prompted for any credentials when you try and access the web service from the browser?

Comment: i am accessing service by pasting below Url :- http://test:25959/_vti_bin/RecruitmentWCF/Recruitment.svc/addnewprospect. and it ask me for user name and password.because my sharepoint site need password .Now i want my service is access without password.

Comment: My requirement is i have sharepoint site and i want to create mobile app for it .to create mobile app i need to develop service .when mobile developer access my service it ask for credentials. and mobile developer want service should not ask credentials .

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly your SharePoint site requires NTLM authentication (i.e. does not allow anonymous access). If this is the case then any resource deployed inside of your SharePoint application (including your service) will require client connections to authenticate.

Have you considered establishing a specific account that can be used by the remote clients to access the service and then passing those credentials explicitly in the calls to the service from the client? This assumes, of course, that you'd be comfortable with the functions and data your service exposes being accessed by a generic account acting as a proxy for many mobile users.

**C# Example:**

```
SomeService client = new SomeService();
client.Credentials = new NetworkCredentials("username","password");
```

**Objective C Example:** 
(I know this example shows an asmx service as opposed to your REST service but the relevant code should be the same): http://www.robertkuzma.com/2011/07/making-a-post-in-objective-c-xcode-to-sharepoint-webservice-requiring-windows-ntlm-authenticaton-for-iphone-or-ipad/

Comment: client.Credentials = new NetworkCredentials("username","password","domain");